# Using enums as List elements in Java possible?

Tags: java, enums

I have a state which could be parametrized by a some `variables` which are discret. So each `variable` could be described with a few `enum` values. But the number of `variables` may vary.

The following code is impossible:

```
    public enum Var0 {
        LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public enum Var1 {
        TOP, BOTTOM;
    }


    // somewhere
    List<enum> vars = new ArrayList<>();  // this is not working 
    vars.set(0,Var0);  // put the whole enum in a list element
    vars.set(1, Var1);

    // somewhere else I want something like this
    for (int i = 0; i < vars.get(i).values().length; i++) {
        vars.get(i).
        for (Enum var : vars.get(i).values()) {
            System.out.println(var.name())
            ..
        }
    }
   // or this ??
   System.out.println(vars.get(1).values()[1]) // 
   ...
```

Any suggestions if/ how one could use `enums` in such scenario are welcome

Comment: Why are not you using `List<Var0>`? `enum` is a reserved keyword in Java. `List<?>` holds a generic and it could be say your class `Var0` as `List<Var0>`.

Answer (score 3):

`Var0` and `Var1` are classes, so it is a compile-time error to write `vars.set(0, Var0)` where an expression is expected. It's also a syntax error to write `List<enum>` because `enum` is not a type; `Enum` is.

However, what you want to do is possible using a list of arrays of `Enum` values:

```java
List<Enum[]> vars = new ArrayList<>();
vars.add(Var0.values());
vars.add(Var1.values());

for(Enum[] e : vars) {
    for(Enum v : e) {
        System.out.println(v.name());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you were asking, but you can actually flatten the list and get rid of the arrays if you really want to:

```
public class EnumsWithInterface {

    public interface VarIf {
        String name();
    }

    public enum Var0 implements VarIf {
        LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public enum Var1 implements VarIf {
        TOP, BOTTOM;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<VarIf>vars = new ArrayList<VarIf>();
        vars.addAll(Arrays.asList(Var0.values()));
        vars.addAll(Arrays.asList(Var1.values()));

        for (VarIf var : vars) {
            System.out.println(var.name());
        }
    }
}
```

Making a `Set` out of it would make even more sense I suppose. Note that you have to check / cast if you want to have an `enum` variable again, as that's lost during compile time.